# How to download images with wget

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, wget

I'm doing this wget script called wget-images, which should download images from a website. It looks like this now:

```
wget -e robots=off -r -l1 --no-parent -A.jpg
```

The thing is, in the terminal when i put `./wget-images www.randomwebsite.com`, it says

```
wget: missing URL
```

I know it works if I put url in the text file and then run it, but how can I make it work without adding any urls into the text file? I want to put link in the command line and make it understand that I want pictures of that certain link that I just wrote as a parameter.

Comment: Just add a command line argument to your script and use that as the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the positional parameters to the `wget` call, i.e. `"$@"`.